# Another unidentified component

Tags: components, identification

I have this component and it does not shows ANY identification (which I never saw before).

Can anybody shed a light on what it can be?

The left/right side is metallic, the rest looks shiny plastic (?)

The dimensions are about 10 mm x 7 mm x 5 mm (L x W x H)
[image]

Comment: Did you measure it with a DMM on the resistance setting? I'm guessing a passive -- capacitor, inductor -- since these rarely have markings in my experience.  But I believe protection devices (e.g. spark gaps, MOVs) are wandering into the unlabeled SMT world, too.

Comment: This could be an SMT mica capacitor.

Comment: My bet would be it's a capacitor, as they rarely have markings on them. You'd have to measure it with a DMM. It could be a 7610 capacitor, though the measurements don't match perfectly.

Comment: wait, that are millimeters, not tenth of millimeters? Is it perfectly symmetric? When you hold it against light, does the light shimmer through?

Answer (score 4):

The most likely ID for that component is as a surface mount capacitor. There are two possible types:

1. Could be a capacitor with a high uF value. In that case it would likely be a multi layer ceramic capacitor (MLCC). The body material would look more like a ceramic material.
2. Could be a very high voltage SMT capacitor. Some types have a body material that provides better dielectric properties than standard ceramic capacitors and could appear to be more of a plastic or poly material. The large body size lends itself the clearance needed between high voltage circuits. At the same time it may very well have a value in the nF or pF range.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a surface mount film capacitor (low value, high voltage). Something like this: https://mouser.com/Passive-Components/Capacitors/Film-Capacitors/_/N-9x371?P=1z0z7ymZ1ywtgm4

Comment: +1 yes, stacked film cap. Typically quite easy to damage by hand soldering.